# Excel 2016 - QAT and Macros

Tags: excel, vba

I built some macros and save the VBA project as .xlam (Excel Add In) file.  The macros (Public Subs) are visible when I go to Excel > File > Options > Quick Access Toolbar(QAT) > Choose 'Macros' from the left drop-down menu.  Then I can add the macros to the QAT so users can click the tools icon to run those macros.

I observed a VERY strange behavior.  Here's what it was before, everything was normal.

[image: Quick Access Toolbar Customization]
[image: VBA Editor]

Here's what it was after.  Things start getting weird.

[image: QAT After]
[image: Editor After]

The only difference is I changed a Sub's argument type from a built-in variable type to a custom class type.  But I haven't run the macro yet.  I'm just entering the code.  But Excel changed the display on two other macros I'm NOT editing (macro names are Check() and CheckAndFix()).

So the questions are:

1) Why Excel GUI displays different formats while I'm entering the code?  And it seem to depends on the variable type I'm typing?  I didn't know that IntelliSense had such an influence on the Excel user interface.

2) Why Excel changed the display of two other Subs that I didn't touch?

By the way, this behavior is reproducible even after computer reboot.  i.e. I can change the argument type between String and cSettings and observed the macro list format changed accordingly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out!

Whenever the code referencing an undefined data type, QAT customization won't work.  The symptoms are:

1)  You'll see the workbook name was prefixed to the macro name on the list.  While in normal situation, you'll just see the macro name.

2) If you associate the macro to a QAT button.  That button won't work.  Whenever you click the button, it will say "*Cannot run the macro'XXX'.  The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled*".  This is misleading as the macro is there and all macro is allowed.

You may ask - "Why your code references some undefined data type?"  It was because my code reference some additional data types (such as Dictionary) that requires additional library (such as "Microsoft Scripting Runtime).  If the library reference was not manually configured, the data type will become 'undefined'.

I'm surprised that the program didn't throw compile error or runtime error.  Instead, it gave the message "macro may not be available for this workbook".